# SSH Connection Time Out on a specific ISP Provider

Tags: windows, azure, ssh, virtual-machine

I am getting connection time out when I try to ssh to my Azure VM on a specific ISP provider, not any other ISP provider. I did notify them about this issue but they do not know what might seem to be the issue.

Also tried to create a new rule to open port 22 on windows Machine, followed all Azure troubleshooting methods, disabled my Firewall, but nothing seems to work, Only when I connect to a different ISP provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take note that the ISP through which you were trying to connect to your Azure VM over port 22 through SSH is blocked over public internet owing to various server side vulnerabilities. The vulnerabilities that the SSH server side is prone to includes Port forwarding, unauthorised SSH access, vulnerable SSH configuration, pivoting and unpatched SSH software. Along with Port 22, most ISPs also block SMB port 445 also on the public internet owing to frequent and hot instances of brute force as well as software manipulation attacks. Since, users are not known to take care or take appropriate security measures for avoiding such attacks, so the ISPs block the inbound as well as the outbound traffic on these ports overall.

You can check by connecting through some other ISP or using cell phone internet in that case as these ports are not blocked over there.

Comment: I did contact my ISP provider and they told me port 22 is opened on my router.  And yes, I can connect to SSH through some other ISP or using cell phone internet. The problem is my Fibre ISP provider.

Comment: Yes, my ISP too told me the same way but when I also tried to access SMB 445 or SSH on port 22, it didn't work for me. So, I tried with my cellphone internet and it worked. Please find the below link for your reference on forwarding the request to SSH port no. 22 to other port: - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-access-port-22-if-isp-has-blocked-port-22

Comment: I can ssh via any other ISP network, except the Fibre one which was recently just installed at my home. And I followed the link instructions but it logged me out of my Azure VM which I had to restart to reset my ssh config file, though the solution could work, but that's not the solution I am looking for, as is took risky for the kind of application I am running on the Azure VM.

Comment: Kindly check whether any firewall software or router is blocking your traffic on Port 22 by running 'netstat -an' command from your command prompt on client system and check whether listening is enabled on that Port or not. Also, check whether a SSH daemon application is running or not.

Comment: I did check and this is the message I get when I do network diagnostic ::: resource (web proxy) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts. Detected  

The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 22, possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn’t find any problems with the firewall on your computer. 
Contact the service provider or owner of the remote system for further assistance, or try again later

Comment: As per the message received by you, it clearly seems that the Azure VM you are trying to connect to isn't responding to SSH connection request from your Windows system. Thus, kindly check whether the NSG(Network Security Group) for your Azure VM or Firewall if deployed has allowed inbound connections for SSH over port 22 from the public internet(any sources) and then check again.

Comment: My NSG does allow inbound connection for SSH over port 22, and I can access it whenever I connect to other ISP providers, not this particular one.

Comment: Add strangely enough I can access and deploy to Azure App services via VS Code Azure CLI tools.

Comment: That means your ISP is simply not forwarding the requests over SSH or blocking it. You can send this errors and the Azure VM NSG screenshots to them for providing proofs that its blocked on their end. Also, provide them screenshots of successful SSH connection from other means, i.e., through cell phone internet.

Comment: I am communicating with them regarding this issue, but they haven't given me any solution, I suspect there is a fault with the router that they have provided to me.

Comment: The issue has been resolved by the ISP, Thanks a lot for your trouble.